# SoapUI responds with 400 bad request

Tags: soap, soapui

I need to make a post request to a web service. The web service has the following structure:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:kn="http://..//soapAction">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
    <kn:InsertOrders>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <kn:XmlOrders>?</kn:XmlOrders>
      <kn:stringLength>?</kn:stringLength>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <kn:LoadListId>?</kn:LoadListId>
   </kn:InsertOrders>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

XmlOrders accepts a string and I'm trying to pass the following xml String in it:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <EXAMPLE xmlns="EXAMPLE"> <HEADER> <ID>G112233</ID> <TR>AB123</TR> </HEADER> <HEADER> <ID>G123123</ID> <TR>AB1234</TR> </HEADER> <DETAIL> <DETAILID>123123123</DETAILID> <TXT>ATR_123</TXT> </DETAIL> <DETAIL> <DETAILID>123123123</DETAILID> <TXT>ATR_123</TXT> </DETAIL> </EXAMPLE>
```

However, SoapUI returns 400 bad request:

```
    Wed May 16 12:41:19 EEST 2018:DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
    Wed May 16 12:41:19 EEST 2018:DEBUG:Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
```

Does anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I post this answer here because this is what solved my problem. I wrapped the XML String inside: 
`"<![CDATA[" + myXMLString + "]]>"`
It actually parsed the XML String without encoding it,or escaping the characters `> , < , & , ', "`.

Comment: This is a very useful solution. It resolves the bad request problem. If you encounter the bad requet 400 messgae you think of request headers and ignore the body. But the request body may also cause this bad request problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could convert XML into String and set it into Method call.

Eventually, When XML gets converted into String

```
' is replaced with &apos;

" is replaced with &quot;

& is replaced with &amp;

< is replaced with &lt;

> is replaced with &gt;
```

refer XML [escaping](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-escape.html) for more details.

Your example XML will become--

```
 &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt; &lt;EXAMPLE xmlns=&quot;EXAMPLE&quot;&gt; &lt;HEADER&gt; &lt;ID&gt;G112233&lt;/ID&gt; &lt;TR&gt;AB123&lt;/TR&gt; &lt;/HEADER&gt; &lt;HEADER&gt; &lt;ID&gt;G123123&lt;/ID&gt; &lt;TR&gt;AB1234&lt;/TR&gt; &lt;/HEADER&gt; &lt;DETAIL&gt; &lt;DETAILID&gt;123123123&lt;/DETAILID&gt; &lt;TXT&gt;ATR_123&lt;/TXT&gt; &lt;/DETAIL&gt; &lt;DETAIL&gt; &lt;DETAILID&gt;123123123&lt;/DETAILID&gt; &lt;TXT&gt;ATR_123&lt;/TXT&gt; &lt;/DETAIL&gt; &lt;/EXAMPLE&gt;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, it seems valid. However, it returns the following error message: `<faultstring>Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (7, 46). ---> Input string was not in a correct format.</faultstring>`. It returns this message either for your above given,modified, String either from my Strings when I use the code: `x=x.replaceAll("<","&lt;");
        x=x.replaceAll(">","&gt;");
        x=x.replaceAll("\"","&quot;");
        x=x.replaceAll("'","&apos;");`.

Comment: @JohnBrant, I'm not sure about your XML whether is correct or not, I see <HEADER> and <DETAIL> nodes two times in your example XML.

Comment: @JohnBrant one more Idea, you could use the encoded XML I have added into answer, and see if it works or try to unescape the XML you have created after doing `replaceAll` and see if its valid XML.

Comment: Red Boy,thanks a lot for your help. Your answer actually makes sense, but it wasn't my case. I posted an answer in case you are interested to what solved my problem.